# Unity3d Windows Phone Live Tile

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-phone, live-tile

How do we implement live tile in Unity3d Windows Phone??
I want the live tile show the current high score.

I have tried this:

```
    #if UNITY_METRO
UnityEngine.WSA.Tile liveTile = Tile.main;
//then we update the tile with our latest high score
//the first three strings are for images (medium,wide,large)
//the last string is for text to display
//you can also pass in an XML file to describe the tile
liveTile.Update("","","", "Best round time: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("angka", 0));
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't work for Prime 31.  I attended the Unity 5 Roadshow and found out Prime 31 is giving away their Windows Phone and Store plug-ins for free (not sure for how long, they have a deal with Microsoft).

[prime31.com](https://prime31.com/plugins#)

They do have support for titles in their **Metro Essentials Plugin**

Here is the code that is included in the demo...

```
    if( GUILayout.Button( "Update Application Live Tile (standard)" ) )
    {
        // first, create the tile data
        var tileData = new StandardTileData();
        tileData.backContent = "I'm on the back";
        tileData.backTitle = "BACK TITLE";
        tileData.title = "Live Tile Title";
        tileData.count = 12;

        // now update the tile
        Tiles.updateApplicationTile( tileData );
    }


    if( GUILayout.Button( "Create Live Tile (Flip)" ) )
    {
        // first, create the tile data
        var tileData = new FlipTileData();
        tileData.backContent = "Back of the Tile";
        tileData.backBackgroundImage = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/Breastfeeding-icon-med.svg/202px-Breastfeeding-icon-med.svg.png";
        tileData.backTitle = "Back Title Here";
        tileData.backgroundImage = "http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/250x250/38333070.jpg";
        tileData.smallBackgroundImage = "Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileSmall.png";
        tileData.title = "Flip Tile Title";
        tileData.wideBackBackgroundImage = "http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-91-03-metablogapi/5775.WideTileAfter_5F00_49305C14.jpg";
        tileData.wideBackContent = "Wide Back Content";
        tileData.wideBackgroundImage = "Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileLarge.png";
        tileData.count = 3;

        // now update the tile
        Tiles.createOrUpdateSecondaryLiveTile( "flippy-tile", tileData );
    }


    if( GUILayout.Button( "Create Live Tile (Iconic)" ) )
    {
        // first, create the tile data
        var tileData = new IconicTileData();
        tileData.iconImage = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/Breastfeeding-icon-med.svg/202px-Breastfeeding-icon-med.svg.png";
        tileData.backgroundColor = Prime31.WinPhoneEssentials.Color.colorFromARGB( 255, 40, 255, 40 );
        tileData.smallIconImage = "http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/250x250/38333070.jpg";
        tileData.wideContent1 = "Wide content 1";
        tileData.wideContent2 = "Wide content 2";
        tileData.wideContent3 = "Wide content 3";
        tileData.title = "Live Tile Title";
        tileData.count = 3;

        // now update the tile
        Tiles.createOrUpdateSecondaryLiveTile( "my-tile", tileData );
    }
```